# W3C Compliance v SEO

Tags: seo, html, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anchor tag inside H1 or H1 inside achor tag : Which is better?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/anchor-tag-inside-h1-or-h1-inside-achor-tag-which-is-better)

I am being advised to place a H2 tag within a A href tag.
To me this does not meet with standards and may even be considered as black hat techniques (or at least grey) I have expressed my concerns but they are insisting its a valid SEO technique.

If I run the code past W3C Markup Validation Service it fails and must admit I do get a bit anal regarding using correct syntax on our website.

Am I being too picky over conforming to standards which in my mind would make it easier for a search engine to read or am I missing a trick here. ?

Answer (score 3):

Placing a hyperlink in a heading is perfectly fine. WordPress posts have their titles in `<hx>` tags (I think it's `<h1>` on the individual post page and `<h2>` on the category pages) and are hyperlinked and they are well indexed and ranked.

What you are seeing is that the HTML is poorly formatted. The anchor goes *inside* the heading. Not the other way around. Remember, inline elements go inside block level elements, not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry no I meant the other way round, a <a href containing a <h2> tag so a block element within a inline element.

Comment: I know what you meant. :) The only difference between the two is one is valid HTML and the other is not. As far as SEO goes there is no difference.

Comment: In html5 an h2 or any block element can be used inside an anchor. It's correct code and it validates. However you should not put it (the anchor with the block-element inside) inside an element that does not allow block elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

In **html5** you can put the any block-type element inside the anchor tag:

> Although previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only
>   containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous
>   versions referred to as “inline” content), the a element is now
>   transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to
>   also contain flow content (essentially, what was in previous versions
>   referred to as “block” content)—if the parent element of that instance
>   of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain flow
>   content.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes

Just use html5 and it will validate. AFAIK putting a header tag inside a anchor tag is not consider black-hat.

Comment: Can you post a link for that bit about Google penalizing sites for excessive HTML errors? I'd like to give that a read.

Comment: I can't find the original article (I've searched for it), but it was an article about new quality indicators. That included that a site would rank better if it would met a number of (new) quality indicators. For example I remember a reputable author/editor, less spelling mistakes, speed, and cleaner html code. I'll edit my answer. "penalize" is a strong word and what I've read is that it would be one of many many quality indicators.

Comment: @JohnConde [Is HTML validation necessary for ranking?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XlKn6I9rSc) from mid-March 2011 still basically says no. Osvaldo, unless you can back up the validation comment better, I'd remove it. (Though I do still think the question should be closed as a dupe.)

Comment: I've removed it.

Comment: It is a dupe indeed. Nice catch.