# Should I link the main article heading?

Tags: seo, html, xhtml, markup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anchor tag inside H1 or H1 inside achor tag : Which is better?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/anchor-tag-inside-h1-or-h1-inside-achor-tag-which-is-better)
>   [Why, on StackExchange sites, is the post title on the question page a link to itself?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/why-on-stackexchange-sites-is-the-post-title-on-the-question-page-a-link-to-it)

Assuming, that I have an article page:

```
http://example.com/articles/article-title
```

with the main content like:

```
<h2 id="main">Article title</h2>
```

**Regarding the SEO and semantic reasons, should I wrap the H2 tag/content in link?**

e.g.

```
<h2 id="main"><a href="/articles/article-title" title="Article title content">Article title</a><h2>
```

or this way:

```
<a href="/articles/article-title" title="Article title content"><h2 id="main">Article title<h2></a>
```

(the `H1` in this particular case is reserved for the topic of the whole website, and linked to the home page.)

As for the end user, clicking this link seems pointless, as this would just do a page refresh. But I sill see those headings linked all around.

Comment: Linking the heading in this way isn't entirely pointless... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/why-on-stackexchange-sites-is-the-post-title-on-the-question-page-a-link-to-it